# mysqldiff all tables in database

Tags: mysql

I'm running mysql diff on a reference db (created from scratch) and a dump of the current DB.

However, the compare dbs option only compares the names of the databases, which in my case are different. Because I'm running on the same server.

```
mysqldiff --server1=jaap@localhost --difftype=sql current:reference
# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# Comparing `current` to `reference`                                   [FAIL]

# WARNING: Cannot generate SQL statements for these objects.
# Check the difference output for other discrepencies.
--- `current`
+++ `reference`
@@ -1 +1 @@
-CREATE DATABASE `current` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */
+CREATE DATABASE `reference` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */
Compare failed. One or more differences found.
```

I there a way to compare all tables in 1 statement?

Comment: For not stopping on the first difference you can just use the [--force](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldiff.html#option_mysqldiff_force) option.

Comment: take `mysqldump` from two databases DB1 and DB2 then use diff command to compare everything.
`diff file1.sql file2.sql`

Comment: Preferably a dump with [`--no-data`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data) if you want to only compare the structure.

Comment: I have already figured out how to dump the schema, the --force option looks promising...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jkavalik mentioned in the comment, the mysqldiff command stops after the first error it finds.
The `--force` option continues to look for more differences!